# Python 3 : Environment Variable setting using exec()

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, exec

I am trying to use an environment variable in a function called by a script.
The issue I am seeing is that the variable is getting set first time, but next time when I call the script, it uses the old variable value.
I am using exec() to call a python script.

Here is the minimum example:

File : test_run.py

```
import os
import sys
from io import StringIO
sigmas = [2.,20.]

for sigma in sigmas:            
            os.environ['SIGMA'] = str(sigma)
            buffer = StringIO()
            sys.stdout = buffer
            exec(open("parent.py").read())

            sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
            result = buffer.getvalue()
            print (result)

            #print('SIGMA', os.environ['SIGMA'])
            buffer.close()
```

File : parent.py

```
import child

sigma_parent = float(os.environ['SIGMA'])

print (' Parent Function Sigma = ', sigma_parent)
child.my_func();
```

File : child.py

```
import os

sigma_child = float(os.environ['SIGMA'])

def my_func():
    print (' Child Function Sigma = ', sigma_child)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Parent Function Sigma =  2.0
 Child Function Sigma =  2.0

 Parent Function Sigma =  20.0
 Child Function Sigma =  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even compile since you `import child` but execute `test.my_func()`. The real problem, however, is your use of `exec()`. Think about what happens when that is executed. The code in *parent.py* will be executed and it will fetch the current value of `os.environ['SIGMA']`. But note that the `import child` is only executed once -- the first time you execute the contents of *parent.py*. Which means the second time your loop executes this statement will not be run again:

```
sigma_child = float(os.environ['SIGMA'])
```

Which means that `my_func()` in *child.py* will only ever see the value assigned to its module level `sigma_child` var the first time the module is imported.

Why are you using `exec()`? It is almost never correct to use `exec()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the compile error, I have corrected it. The reason I am using exec() is to be able to run multiple values of sigma ( and other variables)in a loop. Something like a grid search,